# Can I load page level JS after template JS with handlebars?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, leaflet

I am using handlebars and leaflet together. My libs (leaflet) are loaded in the template along with a minified js file below my main content.

**Main Template**

```
  <main class="app-content">
    {{{body}}}
  </main>
  {{> footer }}
  <!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.2.1/semantic.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src='/js/main.min.js'></script>
```

I believe this is best practice. I have pages where there is mapping data passed through to be rendered in leaflet. How do i get this data to flow nicely as at the moment the page level JS is loading before the leaflet libs and, of course, this will not work.

**Single View**

```
<script>
$(function() {
  var map = L.map('map').setView([{{data.lat}}, {{data.lng}}], 9);
  var os = new L.BingLayer("XXXXXXXX", { type: 'OrdnanceSurvey' });
  os.addTo(map)
});
</script>
```

Any pointers would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this does not work because of Leaflet being placed *after* your script?

Since you wrap your code in [jQuery's document ready shorthand function `$(function () {})`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), it should execute only after your page's DOM is ready, including all synchronous scripts loaded and executed. Therefore, your code would execute *after* Leaflet script has been loaded and executed, even though its tag is placed at the bottom of the page body.

**However** there is another issue in your architecture… it is jQuery itself being loaded *after* your code. Therefore when your code is parsed, jQuery's `$` object is not assigned yet!

A simple workaround would be to load at least jQuery before your page script.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/LujU9IfGJ9AvJGjr5jIK?p=preview

Another solution would be to separate your page script from the content, and to display it into a specific placeholder, after jQuery script at least.

Comment: Thank you, this is good advice and the same conclusion I have come to.